# Auto add items to cart upon login: default behavior?

Tags: magento

John goes to bestwidgets.com and puts 5 red widgets in his cart, logs in then decides not to purchase red widgets and logs out.

John comes back the following day (to the same machine) and decides what he needs are blue widgets. He adds 5 blue widgets to his cart and proceeds to checkout. He then logs in and keeps on trucking thru the one page checkout. Only AFTER he finishes his purchase he realizes that **5 red widgets got automatically added to his cart** (when he logged in, though most people wont even realize that).

John now thinks bestwidgets.com are crooks, cancels his order and never comes back.

Am I missing something here or is this magento’s default behavior!??

Magento Community 1.5.1.0

Comment: (Question posted here after it spent 6 days with no replies in the ever more abandoned magento forum)

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: This sounds to me as though the persistent shopping cart is in effect...this is the way it should work. John should have seen the fact that the 5 red widgets were in his cart as well. If they did not display, then, yes it's an issue.

Comment: @VernBurton Sorrry, Magento Community 1.5.1.0!

Comment: @CCBlackburn, there is no chance for him to see it. not logged in>proceed to checkout>login then you are in the one page checkout pipeline. there is no cart there. asking to notice the change in the minicart maybe hidden somewhere in the page? you're asking too much.

Comment: Shouldn't it be visible in the product review area? my point is that it should be visible somewhere on the checkout page before the user finalises the order

Comment: @CCBlackburn Well, it isnt. Only the higher total caught my eye, thought it might not happen to John...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behavior in Magento, but this has nothing to do with the "Persistent Shopping" feature but with "Quote Life Time". As usual with Magento we left the decision how the store should work to the merchants running the store as they know their market best and what is the best way to configure their store. If you go to System->Configurations under Sales->Checkout in the Shopping Cart tab you should be able to set the number of days the quote (or shopping cart) is remembered (Quote Lifetime (days)). Setting it to 0 should not remember the cart between each login of the customer.

Answer (score 2):

If your using Enterprise: `Enterprise_Persistent` and/or Community `Mage_Persistent` disable them via `app/etc/modules` in the corresponding XML to disable this functionality if your worried about customers not realizing their previous added products are in their cart during checkout.

Comment: I dont have `Mage_Persistent`: http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/503/7640248960.png

Comment: How about: `System -> Configuration -> CUSTOMERS -> Persistent Shopping Cart -> General Options -> Enable Persistence = No` ?

Comment: We might be on to something @B00MER, as I have that option on another install of Mage 1.5.0.1, but it is not available on this particular one, no matter if it is default config, website or store view level...

Comment: That is not the case. I am using 1.5.1.0 and persistent shopping cart was only added in 1.6: http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something here or is this magento’s default behavior!??

Yes it is Magento's default behavior. I get your opinion about the crookishness feeling on this, however, I believe most would say it's to help the customers remember what they were looking at and help them spend money. Subtle difference...

Comment: that subtle difference would be 100% honest, from a customer point of view, if they were asked if they wanted to add what was in their cart when they were last logged in OR at least let them know the "old" items were automatically added back in...